# Spark ML pipeline usage

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I created an ML pipeline with several transformers, including a StringIndexer which is used during training on the data labels.
I then store the resultant PipelineModel which will *later* be used for data preparation and prediction on a dataset which doesn't have labels.

The issue is that the created pipeline model's *transform* function cannot be applied to the new DataFrame, since it expects data labels to be available.

What am I missing?
How should this be done?

Note: My goal is to have a single pipeline (i.e. I'd like to keep the various transformations and ML algorithm together)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should paste your source code.Then your test data format should be consistent with your train data including the feature name.But you don't need label column.
You can refer to [official site](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html)